# Three20 and iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20

I'm trying to complie my app for iOS 4. It includes Three20. I've set the base SDK to "iPhone Device 4.0" and the Deployment Target to "iPhone OS 3.0" but I get this message:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTURLRequestModel", referenced from:
    _OBJC_CLASS_$_MockPhotoSource in MockPhotoSource.o
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: iOS questions belong in Apple's private developer forums still as it and associated tools are governed by your developer agreement/NDA which I suggest you take a look at.

Comment: OK...But i have the same problem with iOS 3.2 and i don't  how to fix it. what i have to do??
Thanks!!

Comment: @Nick Not anymore... iOS 4 and the SDK is public now.

Comment: @Jasarien - note my comment was date stamped :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this thread explains most of the problems.

http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/90a57d469dfcc32d/85750d0c9b7c79de?lnk=gst&q=ios4#85750d0c9b7c79de

Also the updated code is available here..

http://github.com/ECP/three20

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by ensuring that "Build active architecture only" (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH) in the xcode project properties, is checked in both the Three20 project and my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair out as well since adding three20 correctly to your new iOS4 with really basic instructions listed here: http://github.com/facebook/three20 did not work as well.

Issue: Can compile newly three20 to your iOS project and got this error: `Can't find #import "Three20/Three20.h".`

Here is the best solution for those have the same issue:

1. Add your three20 to your iphone project path like this:

   ```
    [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/three20/..
   ```
2. cd three20 dir
3. run:

   ```
   python src/scripts/ttmodule.py -p [yourProjectPath]/[iOSProjectName]/[iOSProjectName].xcodeproj Three20 -c Debug -c Release
   ```
4. go to XCode and do a build now.

Thanks to jverkoey for adding this in, you saved us a lot of headaches.

http://github.com/facebook/three20/commit/0814b1c149cbe987557c88a271f999c3f9f3ae64