# File or Directory Not Found Message

Tags: file-io, xcode4, ios5, instruments

When I profiled (I/O Activity) my application in Instruments, using my iPhone as the device, I saw a bunch of "No Such File or Directory" messages even though the images have been previously added to the project and are visible when I run the app. Has anyone experienced this? Not sure what to do about this or wondering if it's anything to really be concerned about although it bugs me to see those error messages :-)

[image: Instruments->I/O Activity]

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but hopefully to improve the question: did you migrate you project from a previous version of XCode/SDK? If so, a good discussion of possible related issues can be found here: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)

I hope others will contribute to answering your question.