# Linker error for unit test Xcode 4

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode4

my application builds fine when i run it and unit tests built fine as well

unit tests failed(application still fine) when i added some code for CGAffineTransform

behaviour is the same for both simulator and device

error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation", referenced from:
      -[PhysicsObject hasPoint:] in PhysicsObject-23B4A02B8F0621AD.o
  "_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:
      -[PhysicsObject hasPoint:] in PhysicsObject-23B4A02B8F0621AD.o
  "_CGAffineTransformConcat", referenced from:
      -[PhysicsObject hasPoint:] in PhysicsObject-23B4A02B8F0621AD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried suggestions from

http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/
http://sealedabstract.com/code/tired-of-getting-mach-o-linker-errors-when-unit-testing/
[Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)

and nothing works :( i suspect this is related to a framework in particular not being found. I cant seem to identify which though. help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix _CG is `CoreGraphics.framework`