# mach-o-linker error because of a class-CCScrollLayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

I am lost .

i used to use the CCScrollLayer a lot, its a cocos2d class but now i got a strange error- `mach-o-linker`.

1. i have added the classes to my project (`CCScrollLayer.h+m`)
2. i have imported them
3. i have defined :  `CCScrollLayer *scroller`;

then , when i put this line of code :

```
   scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:page1,page2,nil] widthOffset:100];
```

i got mach-o-linker errors !!!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScrollLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in mainScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i have defined armv6 and 7, at the project settings .

what is that ??
i know its not a code error but soemthing different.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should add implementation file for CCScrollLayer to the CompileSources in BuildPhases of your target if it's not there yet

Answer (score 0):

Are they added to the right target? I'm not sure but I think a lot of mach-o-linker errors have the same solution.

Check this post out: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `CCScrollLayer.m` is listed in the *compile sources* stage of your project.

The error means, that a linker failed to find named class in all the objects it has got. Linker's task is to build a final executable with all inter-file links bound correctly, and if it cannot fulfil one of the links it fails.

The common reason to this is "forget" to add one of the compiled files as a source file for linker. As Xcode does that automatically based on all the compiled files -- you, most probably, forgot to add it as a compilable file at all.

Comment: i have draged the files to my project, and i have added the file to the compile-source at the build settings, when i added it in there, i get 2 more errors, and the previous errors stay there ..

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have CCScrollLayer in your compile sources. If it's not there, add it:
Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources