# Restkit.h file not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I am getting the following error show in the image below after upgrading into Xcode 4.5

[image]

what could the error be??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you have to include RestKit framework in your code

Answer (score 1):

add in header search path

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Include RestKit in your app

```
1. add libRestKit.a in your targets>build phases> linked binary with library (Ensure the Framework and all it's headers are imported into your project properly.)
2. project > build setting > Other Linker Flags should be -ObjC -all_load
```

if you want to include RestKit class [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) is the gitHub repo on RestKit

even after adding RestKit Framework and/or class if you get same error then

In your **Build Settings** set YES to `Always search user paths`, and make sure your `Header Search Path` are pointing to the Framework.

Finally, `Build->Clean and Restart Xcode`.

Comment: Just how to point the Header Search Path to the Framework, where to find the framework?
it is giving me Apple Mach-O linker error... no such file or directory: '/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RestKit/RestKit'

Comment: at bottom of project navigator there will be a folder named frameworks with all frameworks which you have included in app , to edit this you have to go targets>build phases> linked binary with library

Comment: oh for linker error have many reasons..try all the solutions of this SO ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device.. hope at least of of them may work for you.. :P