# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using `xcode` to work with `SNAP` package (http://memetracker.org). 
When I Build, I get a few `"Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error"`

I read that I may have to add the right framework but I do not know how I can find what the right framework is.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_Env", referenced from:
        _main in cliquesmain.o
    "ExeStop(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, int const&)", referenced from:
         TPt<TUNGraph>::operator->() const in cliquesmain.o
         TVec<TVec<TInt, int>, int>::operator[](int const&) in cliquesmain.o
         TVec<TInt, int>::operator[](int const&) in cliquesmain.o
         TPt<TExcept>::operator->() const in cliquesmain.o
         TRStr::GetNullRStr() in cliquesmain.o
         TRStr::~TRStr() in cliquesmain.o
         TVec<TInt, int>::operator[](int const&) const in cliquesmain.o
      ...
    "WrNotify(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
        ErrNotify(char const*) in cliquesmain.o
    "TCliqueOverlap::GetCPMCommunities(TPt<TUNGraph> const&, int, TVec<TVec<TInt, int>, int>&)", referenced from:
      _main in cliquesmain.o
    .....
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this memetracker "library" correctly? Check out the tab "build phases", if not then there is probably your problem.

I assume you have the code/library in your project, so you have auto-completion, but to link this library you need to specify where to find it.