# Mach-O Linker Error when using extra framework with target iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, xcode5.1

Hi I created my custom framework by using kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework that can be found in here : https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

I am using XCODE 5.1.1, when I add my framework to the project it gives me this error when my target is 7.1:

ld: in /Users/ozans/Documents/xCodeDeneme/Quiz/BugFixProject/MyFrameworks/MyFoundation.framework/MyFoundation(MyFoundation), too many compact unwind infos in function anon for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I was using 6.0 deployment target as a workaround but with 8.0 coming I want my deployment target supports 7.0.

Before posting this question I looked and tried every solution in here: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device) , but i am still getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I was curious.  I found one reference that suggests the OSX version used to build the library might matter: http://ahmadbushnaq.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/too-many-compact-unwind-infos-aka-what-the/

Comment: Yeah, well my library has been created in Mavericks(10.9) and I am getting the same error in Mavericks(10.9) OSX. Thanks for the effort though.