# Apple mach o linker warning, ignoring my file after renaming app

Tags: file, rename

I have problem with ignoring a file named
    `/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chujbmojjelunhdinhgozymhlaivyflt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/chuj.app/chuj`,

file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):

`/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chuj-bmojjelunhdinhgozymhlaivyflt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/chuj.app/chuj`

I was changing name of my app and something have gone wrong. How can I fix this so the file will be ignored properly?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change name manually, it will break things.

Use the `rename` option from the `refactor` menu.

Comment: yeah i know, but can I change it from this step ?

Comment: what are you renaming, the name that displays on the screen ? you should do it in the `info.plist` file

Comment: Now, I dont want to rename my app. I want to fix my mistake and make it that there won't be any issues while I'm running my app. Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Do you mean rename the project? you can do this change right in xcode in the left pane. As for the error, you can ignore it. delete `DerivedData` folder clean and rebuild it

Comment: No, fix this issue. It's Apple Mach-O Linker Warning

Comment: have you deleted the folder, like I suggested you

Comment: yes I deleted it and now I have another issue :"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device?answertab=votes#tab-top