# YouTube api: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, google-api, youtube-api

Following are the steps I have followed to integrate YouTube upload in my app,

- added libGTLTouchStaticlib.a and respective header folder into my project.
- added libGTLTouchStaticlib.a in General->Linked Frameworks and Library.
- mentioned -ObjC and -all_load in other linker field of build settings
- added systemConfigaration and security framework in General->Linked Frameworks and Library

But when I build its giving following error,

**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: libGTLTouchStaticlib.a looks red color are normal

Comment: Then check the header search path ...

Comment: what it is supposed to be? Please explain

Comment: what is your target version @rishu1992

Comment: For several reason we may get the following issue. The following link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device#comment41741156_5329001

Comment: Change to ios 5 or ios 6

Comment: It will work fine if I remove those lib.a and header files. It worked well in my sample app even after adding lib.a and header file. But when Im adding to my project its giving that error.

Comment: Please exactly what is the error your getting update the question

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Go to Target > Build Phases > Link Binary with libraries :
Remove all your frameworks and add them again !
Hope it works for you !

Comment: I did that it dint work

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation):

    ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Algebra5FirstViewController in .../Algebra5-anwcuftojtxtgkfootneeeqhwztj/Build/Intermediates/Algebra5.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Algebra5.build/Objects-normal/i386/ExercisesViewController.o and .../Algebra5-anwcuftojtxtgkfootneeeqhwztj/Build/Intermediates/Algebra5.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PSLE Algebra5.build/Objects-normal/i386/PSLE_Algebra5FirstViewController.o for architecture i386


LIKE POST FULL MESSAGE

Comment: If I use libGoogleAnalytics.a and libGTLTouchStaticlib. in same project does it give same problem? Becouse it gave duplicate symbol error

Comment: Check architechure REMOVE==> arm64

Comment: Its standard arm7 arm64

Comment: error is :      /Volumes/Development/GYV/Befor clean up/Dazzle_c2.2.1_sharing befor pull/Dazzle/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMReadMonitorInputStream.o)
error is:  ld: 210 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: in finder search GTMReadMonitorInputStream this file , in any play by mistake imported as GTMReadMonitorInputStream.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You @Spynet. I found the problem. I havent deleted all the classes of previous api before using lib.a . Some of the classes were remaining without being deleted. So it was giving above error (duplicate classes). After removing it works

Comment: So your issue solved right so no problem and keep coding and ask question how? what? why? .....

Comment: Definitely Spynet.Thank you! Newbie to ios :-)