# Unity build to xcode with gives error: Apple Mach-O Linker

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I tried to google for the solution. I tried to delete the DerivedData folder but it still doesn't work... Why is this still happening? I am using Xcode version 6.2. Thanks.

Edit: Under the one error has 70 different errors saying various things. There is a warning saying 
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Kevin Chen/Desktop/Parking Director/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/Mushrooms4Eva/Desktop/Parking Director/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a (2 slices)

All of the following links and solutions did not work for me:

https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/apple-macho-linker-error-xcode-61

[Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)

Comment: Please provide more information, at least the concrete error message.

Comment: ANYONE HLP?!?!? Is there at least a way to contact xcode experts at apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your library `libiPhone-lib.a` is not compiled for `arm64`, but your project is set to be compiled for this architecture.

I think all the errors are triggered by this "warning" as the library is ignored, and therefore you may have a lot of missing references.

Your options:

1. Get a version of the lib compiled for `arm64`, or do it yourself, if you have the code
2. Remove `arm64` architecture from your project (which I don't recommend, as you'll need to provide an 64bit build for the App Store, but that's another story)

[image]

**How to make 64bit builds (available from Unity 4.6.2+)**

1. iOS platform
2. Other Settings
3. Scripting Backend => IL2CPP
4. Architecture => Universal (to target both 32 and 64 bit)

**How to build for simulator**

1. Player Settings
2. iOS platform
3. SDK Version => Simulator SDK

Comment: I don't know how to do the lib thing. Can you explain it? Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the library (libiPhone-lib.a) from?

Comment: I have no idea... I just built a game from unity and opened the project up and it gave me that error...

Comment: Ok, if you're doing all this, just for testing / learning, and don't want to deliver this project to the App Store, you should be fine to go with option 2. I will attach a screenshot, where to do this.

Comment: But I need to distribute it to the AppStore

Comment: Can you explain option 1 for me if that works for distributing to the AppStore?

Comment: Does option 2 work for distribution to the AppStore?

Comment: no, not if you hand in a new app, for updates it should be possible to hand in 32bit builds until june or so, not 100% sure about that.. check this out https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Comment: Do you want the scripts of my unity project or my whole file

Comment: Sorry, misundertood your comment.. I thought you're using a third party lib.. check your unity build settings (see updated answer)

Comment: Which Unity version do you use? 64 bit support of Unity is quite new, so I recommend to use unity 4.6.3 for that.

Comment: I upgraded unity and the error is gone! thanks! But when I build it to a simulator, it says my game does not have an architecture that iPhone 5 can execute. How do I fix that problem?

Comment: Good to hear, you got it working.. I updated my answer according to the simulator builds.