# getting Apple Mach-O Linker Error - when tried to build [no error if i clean the project but it reappears again when i tried to built it!]

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Using core data, I was trying to create a simple dairy like application. But when I was trying to compile I am getting error like:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error 
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

To solve this, I deleted all extra code and clean the code and tried lots of way by following the link: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device) but still no solution.

Full error are the follwoing:

```
d /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.app/DiaryPlularSight normal x86_64
    cd /Users/me/Desktop/iOS/DiaryPlularSight
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Intermediates/DiaryPlularSight.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiaryPlularSight.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Intermediates/DiaryPlularSight.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiaryPlularSight_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.app/DiaryPlularSight

duplicate symbol _DiaryEntryMoode in:
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Intermediates/DiaryPlularSight.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NewEntryViewController.o
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DiaryPlularSight-ghxpecfcxggqophakawbugnhrnic/Build/Intermediates/DiaryPlularSight.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DiaryPlularSight.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Diary.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Update: Just added Project folder picture
[image]

Comment: check in build phase there are some .m file add with twice

Comment: i tried to figure out manually. but still I did not find. is there any way to check the duplicate files.

Comment: check this tow file in code ::: NewEntryViewController and Diary

Comment: i checked from the explorer but no duplicates! Just see my project folder. there is no duplicates!

Comment: Go to Windows - Projects and hit delete for the derived data folder of your project. Then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this two file in Compile Sources ::: **NewEntryViewController** and **Diary**

[image]