# XCode7: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, xcode7, cocoapods

I have a problem when I try to compile my iOS application with pod AFNetworking (installed by command 'pod install'). XCode shows this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
```

and this is the detail

```
Ld /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPPEnterprise.app/MYAPPEnterprise normal i386
cd "/Users/MYUSER/MYAPP/MYAPP"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/MYUSER/MYAPP/MYAPP/Libraries/libSMPPayment/Current/Libraries -L/Users/MYUSER/MYAPP/MYAPP/Libraries/libSMPPayment/6.0/Libraries -F/Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F. -FClasses -FLibraries -FPods -FResources -FSettings.bundle -FMYAPP.xcworkspace -FClasses/BO -FClasses/PDF -FClasses/SQLite -FClasses/Utilities -FClasses/Views -FClasses/WebService -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker -FLibraries/ACzip -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser -FLibraries/asi-http-request -FLibraries/base64 -FLibraries/CalendarUI -FLibraries/DirectoryWatchdog -FLibraries/DTAlertView -FLibraries/FMDB -FLibraries/GDataXMLNode -FLibraries/IBAForms -FLibraries/iKEA -FLibraries/LFCGzipUtility -FLibraries/Lib -FLibraries/libSMPPayment -FLibraries/MarqueeLabel -FLibraries/MDSpreadView -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar -FLibraries/minizip -FLibraries/MKNumberBadgeView -FLibraries/MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController -FLibraries/PKRevealController -FLibraries/Shared -FLibraries/SSIndicatorLabel -FLibraries/Star -FLibraries/STTimeSlider -FLibraries/TBXML -FLibraries/TWZipArchive -FLibraries/UIColor-HexValues -FLibraries/VMaskTextField -FLibraries/ZipKit -FPods/AFNetworking -FPods/Headers -FPods/Local\ Podspecs -FPods/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files -FPods/TSCurrencyTextField -FPods/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore -FResources/Docs -FResources/Images -FResources/Settings.bundle -FResources/Sounds -FMYAPP.xcworkspace/xcshareddata -FMYAPP.xcworkspace/xcuserdata -FClasses/PDF/PDFLayout -FClasses/Utilities/AlertView -FClasses/Utilities/Buttons -FClasses/Utilities/Categories -FClasses/Utilities/CustomElementEdit -FClasses/Utilities/CustomLabel -FClasses/Utilities/CustomTableViewController -FClasses/Utilities/CustomTextfield -FClasses/Utilities/DefaultImageView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar -FClasses/Utilities/LoationBroker -FClasses/Utilities/ObjectCacher -FClasses/Utilities/PdfViewer -FClasses/Utilities/Popovers -FClasses/Utilities/SearchBar -FClasses/Utilities/UITableViewController -FClasses/Utilities/Utils -FClasses/Views/Clienti -FClasses/Views/GiroVisite -FClasses/Views/Home -FClasses/Views/Manuale -FClasses/Views/Opzioni -FClasses/Views/Ordini -FClasses/Views/Prodotti -FClasses/Views/Report -FClasses/Views/Scandenziario -FClasses/Views/Sincronizzazione -FClasses/Views/SplitViewController -FClasses/Views/Statistiche -FClasses/WebService/OLD -FClasses/WebService/WebServiceInteraction -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker/ABCalendarPicker -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker/ABCalendarPickerBundle -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker/ABCalendarPickerTests -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker/Demo -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser/AGPhotoBrowser -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser/AGPhotoBrowserTests -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser/src -FLibraries/CalendarUI/Extensions -FLibraries/CalendarUI/Resources -FLibraries/CalendarUI/Views -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Code\ Snippets -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset -FLibraries/DTAlertView/DTAlertView -FLibraries/DTAlertView/DTAlertViewDemo -FLibraries/DTAlertView/DTAlertViewDemoTests -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Pods -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Raw -FLibraries/IBAForms/headers -FLibraries/IBAForms/src -FLibraries/Lib/Debug-iphoneos -FLibraries/Lib/Debug-iphonesimulator -FLibraries/Lib/Distribution-iphoneos -FLibraries/Lib/Release-iphoneos -FLibraries/Lib/Release-iphonesimulator -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/6.0 -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/Current -FLibraries/MarqueeLabel/MarqueeLabelDemo -FLibraries/MDSpreadView/Classes -FLibraries/MDSpreadView/Images -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/Demo -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/screenshots -FLibraries/MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell/MSCMoreOptionTableViewCell -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Additional -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/MZFormSheetController -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Screens -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Documentation -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Headers -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Sample -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source -FLibraries/STTimeSlider/STTimeSlider -FLibraries/STTimeSlider/STTimeSliderExample -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Pod -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Resources -FLibraries/ZipKit/MacFUSE -FPods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking -FPods/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking -FPods/Headers/Private -FPods/Headers/Public -FPods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaFramework -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/AFNetworking -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-MetSales\ Enterprise -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-MYAPP\ Enterprise -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-MYAPP\ Enterprise\ Food -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-MYAPPTC -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/TSCurrencyTextField -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore -FPods/TSCurrencyTextField/TSCurrencyTextField -FPods/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore -FResources/Images/Catalog -FResources/Images/Orders -FResources/Images/Rewind -FResources/Images/Star -FResources/Images/Sync -FResources/Images/Users -FMYAPP.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/MYUSER.xcuserdatad -FClasses/PDF/PDFLayout/CollectionViewCell -FClasses/PDF/PDFLayout/TableViewCell -FClasses/Utilities/Categories/UIImage -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendarTests -FClasses/Utilities/Popovers/SearchBarResultsPopover -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/CustomTableView -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/DBManager -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/iPadCustomKeyboard -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/Ricevuta -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/SettingsInApp -FClasses/Utilities/Utils/StarPrinter -FClasses/Views/Clienti/ArticoliCliente -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Azienda -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Clienti -FClasses/Views/Clienti/EstrattoConto -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Geolocation -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Incassi -FClasses/Views/GiroVisite/AddVisita -FClasses/Views/GiroVisite/WebService -FClasses/Views/Home/HomeView -FClasses/Views/Ordini/GestisciOrdine -FClasses/Views/Ordini/ModalitaPagamento -FClasses/Views/Ordini/OrdiniView -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RiepilogoGiornata -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RiepilogoOrdine -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RigaOrdine -FClasses/Views/Ordini/ShoppingCart -FClasses/Views/Ordini/StoricoOrdini -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/Barcode -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/CatalogoProdotti -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/Slideshow -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/TagliaColore -FClasses/WebService/OLD/SOAP -FClasses/WebService/WebServiceInteraction/BaseObject -FClasses/WebService/WebServiceInteraction/Soap -FClasses/WebService/WebServiceInteraction/Sudzc -FClasses/WebService/WebServiceInteraction/TouchXML -FLibraries/ABCalendarPicker/Demo/ABCalendarPickerDemo -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser/AGPhotoBrowser/Resources -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Raw/DemoGif -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Raw/Image -FLibraries/IBAForms/headers/IBAForms -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/forms -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/input -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/6.0/Headers -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/6.0/Libraries -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/Current/Headers -FLibraries/libSMPPayment/Current/Libraries -FLibraries/MarqueeLabel/MarqueeLabelDemo/Classes -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/Demo/iPadCalendar -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar/classes -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar/support\ files -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/MZFormSheetControllerExample -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/Xcode5\ iOS\ 7\ Example -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Sample/Sample\ Application -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController -FLibraries/STTimeSlider/STTimeSliderExample/STTimeSliderExample -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Tests -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/VMaskTextField -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/VMaskTextField.xcworkspace -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Pod/Assets -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Pod/Classes -FPods/Headers/Private/AFNetworking -FPods/Headers/Private/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/Headers/Private/TSCurrencyTextField -FPods/Headers/Private/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore -FPods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking -FPods/Headers/Public/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/Headers/Public/TSCurrencyTextField -FPods/Headers/Public/WAKeyValuePersistenceStore -FPods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa -FMYAPP.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/MYUSER.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendar.xcdatamodeld -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendarViewController -FClasses/Views/Clienti/ArticoliCliente/Cell -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Clienti/AddCustomer -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Clienti/Cell -FClasses/Views/Clienti/EstrattoConto/Cell -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Incassi/Cell -FClasses/Views/GiroVisite/WebService/Tellus -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RiepilogoGiornata/Cell -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RiepilogoGiornata/Popover -FClasses/Views/Ordini/RigaOrdine/Cell -FClasses/Views/Ordini/StoricoOrdini/Cell -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/CatalogoProdotti/Cell -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/GridView -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/ListView -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/PhotoBrowserView -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/Popvover -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/Price -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/TagliaColore/Cell -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/TagliaColore/Objects -FLibraries/AGPhotoBrowser/AGPhotoBrowser/Resources/Images -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/forms/categories -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/forms/controllers -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/forms/views -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/input/controllers -FLibraries/IBAForms/src/input/views -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/Demo/iPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/MZFormSheetControllerExample/MZFormSheetControllerExample -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/Xcode5\ iOS\ 7\ Example/Xcode5Example -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Categories -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Classes -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Modules -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Other\ Sources -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Headers -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/KIF -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Local\ Podspecs -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/VMaskTextField -FPods/Headers/Private/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/Headers/Public/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa -FPods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/extobjc -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendar.xcdatamodeld/FFCalendar.xcdatamodel -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFMonthCalendarView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFWeekCalendarView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFYearCalendarView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendarViewController/FFButtonAddEventWithPopover -FClasses/Views/Clienti/Clienti/AddCustomer/Models -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/GridView/Cell -FClasses/Views/Prodotti/ListaProdotti/ListView/Cell -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/Demo/iPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar/classes -FLibraries/MELiPadCalendar/Demo/iPadCalendar/MELiPadCalendar/support\ files -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/MZFormSheetControllerExample/MZFormSheetControllerExample/FacebookCompose -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/Xcode5\ iOS\ 7\ Example/Xcode5Example/Xcode5Example -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/Xcode5\ iOS\ 7\ Example/Xcode5Example/Xcode5ExampleTests -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Modules/PKLayerAnimator -FLibraries/PKRevealController/Source/PKRevealController/Modules/PKLog -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Headers/Public -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/KIF/Additions -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/KIF/Classes -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-Tests -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-Tests-KIF -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-Tests-VMaskTextField -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-VMaskTextField -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-VMaskTextField-VMaskTextField -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/VMaskTextField/Pod -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView/FFDayHeaderCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView/FFDayScrollView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFMonthCalendarView/FFMonthCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFMonthCalendarView/FFMonthHeaderView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFWeekCalendarView/FFWeekHeaderCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFWeekCalendarView/FFWeekScrollView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFYearCalendarView/FFYearCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFBlue\ and\ FFRed\ Buttons -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFCategories -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFDateManeger -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEvent -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/Images -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents -FLibraries/MZFormSheetController/Example/MZFormSheetControllerExample/MZFormSheetControllerExample/FacebookCompose/Resources -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Headers/Public/KIF -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/Headers/Public/VMaskTextField -FLibraries/VMaskTextField/Example/Pods/VMaskTextField/Pod/Classes -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView/FFDayHeaderCollectionView/FFDayHeaderCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView/FFDayScrollView/FFDayCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFMonthCalendarView/FFMonthCollectionView/FFButtonWithEditAndDetailPopoversForMonthCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFWeekCalendarView/FFWeekScrollView/FFViewWithHourLines -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFWeekCalendarView/FFWeekScrollView/FFWeekCollectionView -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFYearCalendarView/FFYearCollectionView/FFYearCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEditEvent\ View\ and\ Popover -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEventDetail\ View\ and\ Popover -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Classes -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Constants -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/css -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/img -FLibraries/DTAlertView/Docset/com.darktt.DTAlertView.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/Protocols -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFDayCalendarView/FFDayScrollView/FFDayCollectionView/FFDayCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/FFYearCalendarView/FFYearCollectionView/FFYearCell/FFMonthCollectionViewForYearCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEditEvent\ View\ and\ Popover/FFButtonWithDatePopover -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEditEvent\ View\ and\ Popover/FFButtonWithTimePopover -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEditEvent\ View\ and\ Popover/FFGuestsTableViewCell -FClasses/Utilities/FFCalendar/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/FFEventDetail\ and\ FFEditEvent\ Views\ and\ Popovers/FFEditEvent\ View\ and\ Popover/FFSearchBarWithAutoComplete -filelist /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Intermediates/MYAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP\ Enterprise.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYAPPEnterprise.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -lxml2 -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lReactiveCocoa -lTSCurrencyTextField -lWAKeyValuePersistenceStore -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libIBAForms.a /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libMSCMoreOptionTableViewCell.a -framework Crashlytics -framework Accelerate -framework CoreTelephony -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreData -framework ADFramework -lxml2 -framework ExternalAccessory /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libABCalendarPicker.a -framework EventKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework SystemConfiguration -liconv -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework Bitrace -framework CoreLocation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework QuartzCore -lz -framework MessageUI -framework MapKit -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lSMPPayment -framework StarIO -lPods-MYAPP\ Enterprise -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Intermediates/MYAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP\ Enterprise.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYAPPEnterprise_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/MYUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-amzbjdohegzauqguojdhppmipzoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPPEnterprise.app/MYAPPEnterprise
```

Any help is very welcome, because I don't know what to do anymore.

P.S.: I have this working project. The problem is I have to move it to another PC and, when I try it, it shows this error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you opening .XcworkSpace

Comment: Have you tried 'pod install'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I solved my problem compiling my app with DEPLOYMENT_TARGET iOS 9.2 and then back again to DEPLOYMENT_TARGET iOS 7.0.

Bloody XCode!

Answer (score 4):

I experienced same issue, but my issue was very silly mistake. I opened `.xcodeproj` instead of opening `.xcworkspace`.

So double check it you have not opened your project using `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: .xcodeproj is always fine untill we have pods. Opening .xcworkspace did that trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you moving them to another system some time it may lock.so do this process.just remove the podfile folder in your project and also exe file of pod.

Now do this
1)Go to terminal and type cd and drag your folder next to cd

you will see like this cd /Users/name/Desktop/holla/MyProjects/customer/support

2)In next line type this...**Touch podfile**

you can see a notepad and just paste you podfile. if afnetworking paste this
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'....

3)Now close the notepad and type **pod install**.it will take sometime and once it is done.close the terminal and open the projectname.Workspace.

Comment: Nothing. Same problem. 
`Installing AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Installing ReactiveCocoa (2.5)
Installing TSCurrencyTextField (0.1.0)
Installing WAKeyValuePersistenceStore (1.2)`

Comment: There is no error on terminal when I install pod
`pod install
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.3 is available.
To update use: gem install cocoapods --pre
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Using ReactiveCocoa (2.5)
Using TSCurrencyTextField (0.1.0)
Using WAKeyValuePersistenceStore (1.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats`

Comment: And XCode shows always
`ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device....Check this link it will solve your problem...overwriting is the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me, maybe they work for you, too:

1. Comment the pod command in Podfile and install the pod.
2. Then uncomment the pod command and reinstall the podfile.
3. And then open the .xcworkspace

Comment: Nope. I tried to follow your steps but it didn't solve the problem. Thanks by the way for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem just now. Here's how I solve it:

Go to Project -- > Build Phases -- > Link Binary With Libraries -- > remove `libAFNetworking.a`