# GCM linker command failed with exit code 1: Apple-Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, xcode7

What I have done after 2 days of reading stack overflow:

**Keywords to problem:**

> "Apple-Mach-O Linker Error",
>   "libGGLCore.a(Clientanalytics.pb.o,Icore.pb.o,Jspb.pb.o,LogsAnnotations.pb.o
>   ...)", "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBExtensionRegistry"
>   ,"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBGeneratedEnumDescriptor" ....

I Don't use pod. Manually Download files from `Github`

So I am stuck. How do I solve the problem(s) displayed in the image below:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: List of errors]

Answer (score 1):

Did you download all the dependent pods? To make GCM work, you need `Google`, `GoogleCloudMessaging`, `GGLInstanceID`, `GoogleInterchangeUtilities`, `GoogleIPhoneUtilities`, `GoogleNetworkingUtilities`, `GoogleSymbolUtilities`, and `GoogleUtilities`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various errors in your code as per your description. Some of the possibilities are:
 1. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)
 2. Importing `QuartzCore` in the project might fix the issue too.
 3. Cleaning the project and restarting might help you too.
 4. Changing the architecture of the project from `armv6` to `armv7` or `arm64` could help too.
 5. Moving the linked library of GCM to another folder also causes this issue. Please check it out too.