# Objective C - Custom struct 'make' method similar to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake

Tags: ios, objective-c, struct

I've written a custom struct in a separate header file. It looks something like this

```
typedef struct RequestSpecifics {
    BOOL includeMetaData;
    BOOL includeVerboseData;
} RequestSpecifics;
```

Now I want to make a custom 'make' method, similar to the CoreLocation struct CLLocationCoordinate2 `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` method.

I've tried two different ways. While both ways give no errors in the .h file, I do get errors when I want to use the make method.

**Method 1:**

```
extern RequestSpecifics RequestSpecificsMake(BOOL includeMetaData, BOOL includeVerboseData);
```

Throws:

> **Apple Mach-O Linker**
>
> "_RequestSpecificsMake", referenced from:
>
> Error Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Method 2:**

```
extern RequestSpecifics RequestSpecificsMake(BOOL includeMetaData, BOOL includeVerboseData) {
    RequestSpecifics specifics;
    specifics.includeMetaData = includeMetaData;
    specifics.includeVerboseData = includeVerboseData;
    return specifics;
}
```

Throws:

> **Apple Mach-O Linker**
>
> Error Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Usage example:**

```
RequestSpecificsMake(NO, NO)
```

I've checked all [common solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device) for the Apple Macho-Linker error but nothing seems to work or the solutions are not relevant.

So how do I correctly implement the 'make' method for a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try

`static inline` instead of `extern`

```
static inline RequestSpecifics RequestSpecificsMake(BOOL includeMetaData, BOOL includeVerboseData) {
    RequestSpecifics specifics;
    specifics.includeMetaData = includeMetaData;
    specifics.includeVerboseData = includeVerboseData;
    return specifics;
}
```

or if you want to use `extern` then you need to write it in .m file.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently method 2 should be the implementation and it should not be in the .h file. Naturally, I need a `.m` file as well. This should be the correct way to do it:

**.h file**

```
RequestSpecifics RequestSpecificsMake(BOOL includeMetaData, BOOL includeVerboseData);
```

**.m file**

```
RequestSpecifics RequestSpecificsMake(BOOL includeMetaData, BOOL includeVerboseData) {
        RequestSpecifics specifics;
        specifics.includeMetaData = includeMetaData;
        specifics.includeVerboseData = includeVerboseData;
        return specifics;
    }
```

In the end I had to combine both methods! Also, by the looks of it, the `extern` keyword is not required.