# Python Kivy: In Xcode9.1 and OS high sierra, I build failed with 73 issues

Tags: python, kivy

Please help me. I have a big problem and cannot solve in 46hours.
at first, look at my pict.

My picture

[image]

Second look this URL.

[How to build ipa in kivy](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/06/14/how-to-deploy-kivy-app-to-ios-and-android/)

I certainly did build as described in the URL. But still error happening like my picture. And 73!! so many problem.

Please somebody tell me how to fix it.

- cython is 0.23
- kivy is 1.10.0

and here is toolchain status:

[image: toolchain status]

Added picture of about "Enable bitcode"

[image: Enable bitcode]

Comment: To eyllanesc  
Thankyou edit better :)

Comment: Is "Enable bitcode" set to no?

Comment: To  EL3PHANTEN: Yes. I will add that picture.

Comment: Try "Menu > Product > Clean"

Comment: take a look at some of these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device

Comment: Thankyou el3phanten:) first, i tried Clean, but still error. And now i check your url. then i will report as comment.

Comment: To EL3PHANTEN: I tryed but still error 73.

Comment: Ok, there seems to be the same error: "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" for a number of reasons. There are several answers on the link above, with more than 100 votes. Did you try them all?

Comment: To EL3PHANTEN: Please give me your opinion. In my case, Basically, is it extremely unusual for this kind of error to occur?

Comment: Sorry, there were items that I have not tried yet. I will try it immediately. Thank you.