# FacebookLoginSDK 4 Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift, linker, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate `FacebookLogin SDK 4` into my IOS app using `Swift 3`. I added the following 3 frameworks: `Bolts`, `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit`. I changed my `Info.plist` according to Facebook documentation, created the Bridging header file, and added its path to my Build Settings.

Once I add the following line in my `AppDelegate.swift` file, I am getting:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }
```

I tried the options provided here: [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)
None of them helped (unless I am missing something). Has anyone else had a similar problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have u added this method in app delegate

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])
}
```

also this one in  willResignActive method

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
{
     FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added those methods, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Linker command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: @codedev . Once remove fb integration run build the project , install fb integration again .

Comment: I just tried it, deleted all the frameworks and added them back. Still same error. When I comment out the lines related with FBSDK it works fine.

Comment: @codedev Create one new project add fb integration in that & check whether its working fine or not