# Paytm SDK in swift 5 and Xcode 10.2 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, mach-o, paytm

I'm trying to integrate Paytm SDK in my iOS Application with Swift version 5 (Also tried with swift 4.2 and having the same error).

I used the SDK available on the official website and followed the same steps as mentioned but I'm getting this error.

**Apple Mach-O Linker error**

> ld: /Users/jass/Desktop/edurama-ios/PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK compiled with older version of Swift language (unknown ABI version 0x06) than previous files (unknown ABI version 0x07) file '/Users/jass/Desktop/edurama-ios/PaymentSDK.framework/PaymentSDK' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Try to `clean build folder` or have a look on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device

Comment: Tried, yet no luck. If I delete the SDK file, the project compiles successfully.