# Build failed because the Mach-O file couldn’t be generated

Tags: ipad, swiftui, swift-playground

I am using Swift Playgrounds on iPad, and every time I try to start my app, it just says “Build failed because the Mach-O file couldn’t be generated.” I have no idea what this means. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eci7a.jpg)

I tried restarting my device, clearing the app data and restarting it, and I deleted Playgrounds and reinstalled it again. There are no errors in the code, so I don’t know what’s going on here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Mach-O Linker Error when compiling for device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device)

Comment: That’s XCode, and I don’t have a Mac (Even though I want one so bad).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this happened to me, and the problem arose from having swift files of the same name in different folders.  Once I renamed all files to be unique, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it drove me nuts. After a while I realized that the problem was that I was missing the `@main` tag in my app declaration ;(

So yeah, that might be your problem. If it's not, it's probably something related with the computer attempting and failing to connect all the dots to create the final project

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35447804)